# how to protect the public_html folder on shared server?

Tags: php, laravel, public-html

I've deployed a laravel app to a shared host. All my files are sitting within the public_html folder, including an .env file which contains my database credentials. According to some articles I've read online, the public_html folder is somehow accessible to malicious users...how is that possible and how can I protect it ?

Answer (score -3):

In project/public/index.php

Look for the following:

```
require __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/autoload.php’;
$app = require_once __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/app.php’;
```

And Update them to:

```
require __DIR__.’/../project/bootstrap/autoload.php’;
$app = require_once __DIR__.’/../project/bootstrap/app.php’;
```

You Might Face problems running composer unless you are uploading the vendors directory.

Reference: https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

Comment: Thank you very much...the article makes sense. I'll try it out....now how's the public_html accessible to malicious users ? I have a password and username for my Cpanel, right ? so how can someone access the files within the public_html folder ?

Comment: I've followed the tutorial, and I'm getting an error. it says 'View[main] not found'. main is my home page view.
What could be the problem ?

Comment: Fixed it...I ran php artisan cache:config ...then php artisan cache:clear..
Thanks...